# Cannot render groovy sh script with environmental variable that uses jq

Tags: jenkins, jq, aws-cli, amazon-emr, jenkins-groovy

I have this line here that is inside of a groovy function and i am trying to return a cluster ID

```
EMR_ID = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws emr list-clusters --active --profile \'${PROFILE}\' | jq -r '.Clusters[] | select (.Name=="\'${ENV}\'-emr-cluster") | .Id'")
```

Without the environmental variables, this works fine.
so the $PROFILE param is set to dev and the $ENV is set to aws-dev.

I keep getting the error that complains about the $ENV var, saying that an unexpected bracket is showing up

Comment: What is the value of ${ENV}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realising that the jenkins snippet generator was actually useful I used this:

```
sh '''jq -r --arg env "${ENV}" \'.Clusters[] | select (.Name=="\\($env)-emr-cluster") | .Id\' '''
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

It is rarely a good idea to pass environment variables using string-interpolation. There are much better ways.

One you might consider is modifying your invocation of jq as follows:

```
jq -r --arg env "${ENV}" '.Clusters[] | select (.Name=="\($env)-emr-cluster") | .Id'
```

Here, `$env` is an ordinary jq variable, or more accurately perhaps, a defined constant.

Comment: This works perfectly on a bash terminal, but how do i get this working on a groovy script? I need to take into account of the formatting that groovy needs to do